# ios/xcode: UIAlert Not stopping action and clicking OK crashing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, dismiss

After saving something to core data, I would like to show an alert thanking the user.  When the user clicks OK, I would then like to dismiss the modal view controller from which the save is carried out.

However, the alert is not stopping the dismissal of the controller and further when you hit ok is crashing the app.  My understanding is that these crashes can happen when the controller no longer exists.  In this case, however, I'm launching the alert before dismissing the controller.

Can anyone spot what is going wrong?

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Code:

```
if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            [self fireAlert];
            // Dismiss View Controller
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to save record.");
                NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
            }
         }

-(void) fireAlert {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank you!" message:@"We appreciate your feedback" delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dismissing the view controller so `delegate:self` causing the crash because after

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

`self` is no longer available. It is deallocated and sending a message to deallocated object is causing the crash.

Try making `delegate:nil` if you dont want to use `UIAlertView` delegate methods.

or use delegate methods , make sure you have `UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>`

then do

```
if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            [self fireAlert];

        } else {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to save record.");
                NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
            }
         }

-(void) fireAlert {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank you!" message:@"We appreciate your feedback" delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
   // Dismiss View Controller
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: delegate nil fixed it.  Will mark correct as soon as it lets me.  Thx!